# Show that $(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k|^p)^\frac{1}{p}=1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Saw a question where I was asked to show that $(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k|^p)^\frac{1}{p}=1$

Where the surface of unit sphere centered around the origin of a linear space with the $l^p$-norm is the locus of points $(x_1, x_2,...) $

I have no clue on how to go about proving this. I had thought about using the fact that I'm dealing with a unit sphere, thus:

$x_1^2+x_2^2+....=1^2 $

But this results in: $(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k|^2)^\frac{1}{2}=1$

How do I proceed?

Comment: What are the $x_k$? For example obviously for $x_k=\begin{cases}1 &k=1\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$ it holds and for $x_k=1/k$ it doesn't.

Comment: Your example with $(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^2)^{1/2}$ uses the unit sphere under the $\ell^2$-norm.  Do you know what the unit sphere in the $\ell^p$-norm is?

Comment: @s.harp : It's written in a hard to parse order, but OP's sentence starting "Where the surface..." asserts that $(x_k)_k$ is any point on the $\ell^p$ unit sphere.

Comment: @EricTowers I don't know what a unit sphere in $l^p$-norm mean. Can you help me  define it?

Comment: [Unit balls in normed vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere#Unit_balls_in_normed_vector_spaces)

Comment: @EricTowers I've clicked on the link you provided and I think I now understand what a unit sphere in the $l^p$-norm is. However that means the solution to the question above is trivial. Isn't it?

Comment: That's what I understand.  Are you sure you saw a *question* and not a *definition*?